# Check the label of a data with new features that hasn't been encoded

Tags: pandas, machine-learning

After training and testing a data set ,I wanted it to predict the label of a certain dataset with only features. On normal examples I used

prediction = clf.predict(data)

but since the data I'm working with needed to be encoded,it resulted in a column size of 2891 after one hot encoding. So, now how do I check the label of a new feature that has not been encoded?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is little unclear. However I understand that the issue here is that test data contains new categories which are not there in training data set . So if you do one hot encoding for training data set, you may get a matrix of shape lets say: (10,m_train) but when you do encode test data, you may get a matrix of shape (15,m_test). So obviously , you can not use the old model to predict these new test data labels. I think  it is better to reframe your training dataset which consist of all new categories and then shuffle the data set and divide it into traning and test dataset.Or the other option is that you can while encoding your test data , you can ignore the new categories in test data. See below example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np
onehot = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore')
y_train = onehot.fit_transform(np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(3,1)).toarray()
print(y_train)
```

This will result in below matrix:

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

And for test set, it will mark all unknown categories as zero keeping the dimensions of your test data matrix same as training data set.

```
y_test = onehot.transform(np.array([1,2,4]).reshape(3,1)).toarray()
print(y_test)
```

Notice [0,0,0] for category '4' here.

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.]]
```